# Calculation loops in different categories

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm new in using python. I have 4 years of data as below:

| Depth | vo | Year | dy | dx |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.49402 | -0.649 | 2004 | 0.49402 | 8333.4 |
| 1.54137 | -0.642 | 2004 | 1.04735 | 8333.4 |
| 2.64566 | -0.637 | 2006 | 1.104294 | 8333.4 |
| 3.81949 | -0.628 | 2007 | 1.1738 | 8333.4 |
| 6.44061 | -0.141 | 2007 | 1.258729 | 8333.4 |
| 7.92956 | -0.211 | 2008 | 1.488945 | 8333.4 |
| 9.57299 | -0.040 | 2008 | 1.643436 | 8333.4 |

and want to calculate each year with this step:

```
df2 = df1.loc[df1['Depth'].between(0, 25),:] #25 m below sea level
df2['Area [m2]'] = df2['dx']*df2['dy']
df2['Tpr [m2_s]'] = df2['Area [m2]']*df2['vo']
df2['Tpr [sv]'] = df2['Tpr [m2_s]']*1e-6
df25_A = df2.sum()
df25_A.to_csv(rf"FILE.csv")
```

Can I calculate each year and save it in a different year file? Perhaps using loops? How to do it?

I usually separate the data first and run the data one by one. Is there a more effective way? Thank you.

Comment: What specific year does this code process, and how would you change it to process a different one?

Comment: @ScottHunter I want to count each year from 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007 and 2008.

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. Please remember to always include the pandas tag when asking pandas questions, as described in the Python tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can calculate each year and save it in a different year file using a loop. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load your data
df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv')

# Group the data by 'Year'
grouped = df.groupby('Year')

# Loop through each group (year)
for year, group_data in grouped:
    # Filter the data for the current year
    df_year = group_data[group_data['Depth'].between(0, 25)]
    
    # Calculate the area
    df_year['Area [m2]'] = df_year['dx'] * df_year['dy']

    # Calculate the Tpr
    df_year['Tpr [m2_s]'] = df_year['Area [m2]'] * df_year['vo']

    # Calculate the Tpr in sv
    df_year['Tpr [sv]'] = df_year['Tpr [m2_s]'] * 1e-6

    # Summarize the data for the current year
    year_summary = df_year.sum()
    
    # Save the summary data for the current year to a CSV file
    year_summary.to_csv(f'Year_{year}_summary.csv')
```

It does the following things:

- It reads the data from a CSV file and stores it in a dataframe.
- It splits the dataframe into smaller dataframes based on the year.
- For each year, it filters the data by depth, calculates the area and the Tpr of each cell, and converts the Tpr to sv.
- It sums up the data for each year and saves it to a CSV file